# Android emulator disconnects while starting

Tags: android, connection, emulation

I have run into the problem of the emulator disconnecting while starting.  The disconnection occurs when the Android splash screen displays.  I then kill the emulator and start it again.  This work most of the time but, occasionally it requires another kill/start cycle.

Android splash screen:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Android splash screen displays"?

Answer (score 0):

Using adb kill-server seems to fix the problem.